# Why is AntiXss Library not working with Eval()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, antixsslibrary

I am working on a simple ASP.NET application to prove the use of AntiXss library. The library is very powerful and it is working fine with me except with Eval() in aspx pages. For example, if I have a label control like the following:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="CommentsLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
```

**How will I be able to use AntiXss with it?**

I followed [this example mentioned HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cisg/archive/2008/10/01/asp-net-data-binding-and-antixss-encoding.aspx), and I added the library to the label control by doing the following:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="CommentsLabel" Text='<%#Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Comments"].ToString()) %>'/>
```

And my instructor is still telling me it is vulnerable and I don't know why. Then, instead of using `AntiXss.HtmlEconde()` , I used `Encoder.HtmlEncode()` in the previous line

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="CommentsLabel" Text='<%#Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Comments"].ToString()) %>'/>
```

**EDIT:**

And based on the scanning tool which my instructor is using it, he is still telling me that it is vulnerable. **So how to use this library with Eval or Data Binding in general?**

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. The `HtmlEncode` is not working and you get an error ? - OR - your instructor says that even if you use it you can sill break the html code, or inject javascript code ?

Comment: The code is fine and the application is working with these lines. My instructor has a scanning tool and he told me that those last two lines are still vulnerable and I don't why. Is it because I am using the library incorrectly or what?

Comment: This question is like a trivial, you need to find the real vulnerable that is talking about. Is talking about breaking the html code, or inject link to other page, or insert javascript code that can runs.